# Which Timer can I use to control a servo with Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, servo, timers

I would like to control 2 motors using Timer2 @ 200Hz. The frequency of the timer is printed in the main loop every second. I'm using an Arduino Uno with two interrupt used for the encoders connected to pin 2 and 3.

**The problem**

The timer runs at 200Hz as expected but the motors are shaking even if I ask them not to spin. The Timer2 is not required by the servo library.

How can I solve this problem? How do you handle Timer interrupts and servo routines?

**CODE**

```C++
#include <Servo.h>
Servo motorDx, motorSx;
[...]

void setup()
{
  // Setup Timer2 @ 200Hz
  cli(); // Stops interrupts

  TCCR2A = 0;// set entire TCCR1A register to 0
  TCCR2B = 0;// same for TCCR1B

  // set compare match register for 200 Hz increments
  OCR2A = 77;// = (16*10^6) / (200*1024) - 1 -> 200 Hz

  // turn on CTC mode
  TCCR2A |= (1 << WGM21);
  // Set CS10 and CS12 bits for 1024 prescaler
  TCCR2B |= (1 << CS20) | (1 << CS21) | (1 << CS22);  
  // enable timer compare interrupt
  TIMSK2 |= (1 << OCIE2A);

  sei(); //enable global interrupts

  attachInterrupt(0, MSencVel, RISING);
  attachInterrupt(1, MDencoder, RISING);
  motorDx.attach(10, 1000, 2000); 
  motorSx.attach(11, 1000, 2000); 
}

void loop()
{
  if(micros()-tOld >= 50000)
  {
    tOld = micros();
    count += 1;
    if(count >= 20) // Runs @ 1 Hz
    {
      count = 0;
      serialRoutine();
      // prints number of ISR/sec
      Serial.println(contIsr)     
      contIsr=0;
    }
  }
}

ISR(TIMER2_COMPA_vect)
{
  //sendValuesToMotors();
  motorDX.write(90);
  contIsr++;
}
```

Comment: What motors exactly are you attempting to control?

Comment: DC motors with a fully working H bridge.

Comment: Don't H-bridges just use steady state or PWM signals? servo uses its own interrupts to generate the PPM signal used by hobby servos, ESC's, and RC radios.